# expectation of a minimization problem

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization

Dose the following inequality hold?

$E_i[min_{y\in D} \ \ y^Tx_i] \leq min_{y\in D} \ E_i[y^Tx_i]$

Please help me to prove or disprove the above inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first expectation, the $y$ can be different for each $x_i$.
In the second expectation, we are only minimizing over $y$ that are the same for each $x_i$.
So the second expectation is minimizing over a subset of the situations in the first expectation.  So the first min is at least as low as the second min.
Another way: In the first expectation, you minimize over $(y_1,y_2,...y_n)$.  In the second, you minimize over $(y_1,y_1,...,y_1)$

Comment: So you mean that it is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.